# Can multidimensional arrays be passed via @MethodSource (junit 5.1)?

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5, parameterized-unit-test

I'm trying to pass two-dimensional arrays to a parameterized test. The one-dimensional array works as expected, but junit complains on the second with "Error resolving parameter at index 0". Is this not supported or am I using the wrong syntax?

(junit 5.1.0)

```
// This is ok
static Stream<int[]> arrayStream1(){
    return Stream.of( new int[] {1}, new int[] {2});
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("arrayStream1")
void test1(int[] par) {
    assertTrue(true);
}

// This is not
static Stream<int[][]> arrayStream2(){
    return Stream.of( new int[][] {{1,2}}, new int[][] {{2,3}});
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("arrayStream2")
void test2(int[][] par) {
    assertTrue(true);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Could you please open an issue over at https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/new/choose Thanks!
On 5.4.0-SNAPSHOT, the error message reads: _org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Error converting parameter at index 0: No implicit conversion to convert object of type [I to type [[I_

Comment: Thanks -- fup2 https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1665

Answer (score 1):

As of JUnit Jupiter 5.3.1, that is not supported.

For insight into what the JUnit Team is doing in this regard, please see the corresponding [GitHub issue](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1665).

However, both of the following workarounds will help you achieve your goal for the time being.

**Wrapping in Object[]**:

```
static Stream<Object[]> arrayStream3() {
    return Stream.of(new Object[] { new int[][] { { 1, 2 } } }, new Object[] { new int[][] { { 2, 3 } } });
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("arrayStream3")
void test3(int[][] par) {
    System.err.println(Arrays.deepToString(par));
}
```

**Wrapping in Arguments**:

```
static Stream<Arguments> arrayStream4() {
    return Stream.of(arguments((Object) new int[][] { { 1, 2 } }), arguments((Object) new int[][] { { 2, 3 } }));
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("arrayStream4")
void test4(int[][] par) {
    System.err.println(Arrays.deepToString(par));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, 

Should not it be `Arguments.of((Object) new ...` in place of `arguments(...` ?

Comment: `Arguments.of(...)` exists since JUnit Jupiter 5.0. `Arguments.arguments(...)` exists since 5.3 and is an alias for `Arguments.of(...)`. So, `arguments()` in my example is a `static` import.